# JSON to RDD of array (Spark Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a JSON file that has format like this-

```
[
   {
    "review_id": "lWC-xP3rd6obsecCYsGZRg",
    "stars": 4.0,
    "embedding": [
     -0.09249028478260879,
     0.16608999068322985, 
     0.19999902267080732
    ]
},
{
    "review_id": "lWW-xP3rd6obsecCYsGZRg",
    "stars": 3.0,
    "embedding": [
        1.09249028478260879,
        0.6608999068322985, 
        3.9999902267080732
    ]
}
]
```

I want to select just the last key (ie embedding) and convert it into an RDD of arrays - one embedding on each line. I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: spark version & can add expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

```
     import spark.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};


       val df = Seq(("""[{"review_id": "lWC-xP3rd6obsecCYsGZRg","stars": 
       4.0,"embedding": [-0.09249028478260879,0.16608999068322985,0.19999902267080732 
      ]},{"review_id": "lWW-xP3rd6obsecCYsGZRg","stars": 3.0,"embedding": 
       [1.09249028478260879, 
     0.6608999068322985,3.9999902267080732]}]""")).toDF("Demographics")

     inputDF.show(false)

      val schema = DataType.fromJson(json).asInstanceOf[StructType]//create ur struct

     finally explode column as per your need
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply read the json file using option of multiline to true and then select the column that is required. you would get the dataframe as output of that operations and you can convert that to rdd using `.rdd` operation.

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("/stacktest.json").select("embedding")
val arrayofrow= df.rdd.collect()
```

you can use collect to convert that to array[row] and use it as you want or you could also use the dataframe in a way you want.